# Setting ranges for array, keeps skipping first row?

Tags: vba, excel

Nothing wrong with the functionality of the code. Just something I don't quite understand. when defining 'data', I start at `Cell(1, 1)`, which is supposed to be A1 right? I don't want it to start at A1, I want it from A2 (Because headers). How come I can only get the first row of data AKA A2:A* when using `Cells(1, 1)`? Shouldn't it be `Cells(2, 1)`?

```
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim columnCount As Integer
Dim mainsht As Worksheet

Set mainsht = Worksheets("DATA")
'So array size will dynamically change with updates
rowCount = mainsht.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
columnCount = mainsht.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column

' load the headers and data to an array '
headers = Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, columnCount).Value
data = Cells(1, 1).Resize(rowCount, columnCount).Value
```

Comment: I'd define data = Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(2, 1).Resize(rowCount, columnCount))

Comment: Interesting, could you explain the difference in doing so? Also would it be affected by removing the .Value?

Comment: Well your example should work fine with data = Cells(2, 1).Resize(rowCount, columnCount).Value for defining a variant array of data minus row 1 headers. That's exactly what data = Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(2, 1).Resize(rowCount, columnCount)) would do also if you called data.Value. Both the same thing, one's a variant array the other's a range, personal preference but back to the original point - I do believe if you're after data without the headers it should start from (2,1) = (row,col)

Comment: FWIW, if you start from row 2, you want to subtract 1 from `rowCount` when resizing.

Comment: @Will, thanks but defiing a variant array here is actually very important to the purpose of the entire code (huuuuge amounts of uniform data manipulation). I probably should have specified that.

Comment: @Rory, I'm still on my first cup of coffee today, so can't really connect the dots.. But I'm guessing that is where that 1 row went. Thanks!